# Not able to implement async task for uploading image to firebase

Tags: android, kotlin

I am stuck on how to implement the code in the finally block using asynctask. The image takes time to upload and by then the user may have already clicked on the sendButton taking him to the next activity and sending the imageURL as null.
If I give it time before I press send, i.e. wait till the download URL pops up in the Log, the app works just fine. So I need help as to how to implement this code in the async task. I tried to put most of the code in a new function but then I was able to call the function in the myTask class.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snaps)
    val userInputMessage = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userinput)
    val sendButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.sendButton)
    userInputMessage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    sendButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    checkStoragePermission()
    val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imagebutton)
    imageButton.setOnClickListener {
        imageButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        createImageGallery()
        lock()
        val storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val galleryFolder = File(storageDirectory, resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
        val argument = createImageFile(galleryFolder)
        val outputPhoto: FileOutputStream? = FileOutputStream(argument)
        try {
            textureview.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, outputPhoto)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            // Do this part async
            val imageTBP: Uri = Uri.fromFile(argument)
            val storageRef = storage.getReference().child("images").child(imagetbpname)
            val uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(imageTBP)
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }).addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>{
                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<Uri> {
                    downloadURL = it.toString()
                    Log.i("URL", downloadURL)
                })
            })

            try {
                if(outputPhoto != null){
                    outputPhoto.close()
                }
            } catch (e: IOException){
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
            }
            sendButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            userInputMessage!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
    sendButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, ChooseUserActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("imageName", imagetbpname)
        Toast.makeText(this, "download URL $downloadURL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        intent.putExtra("imageURL", downloadURL)
        intent.putExtra("Message", userInputMessage!!.text.toString())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

class myTask: AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Void? {

        return null
}

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this instead of upper approach. and make you `val uploadTask` is global variable

```
`sendButton.setOnClickListener {
   uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener{
      Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }).addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>{
          storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<Uri> {
              downloadURL = it.toString()
              val intent = Intent(this, ChooseUserActivity::class.java)
              intent.putExtra("imageName", imagetbpname)
              Toast.makeText(this, "download URL $downloadURL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              intent.putExtra("imageURL", downloadURL)
              intent.putExtra("Message", userInputMessage!!.text.toString())
              startActivity(intent)`
              Log.i("URL", downloadURL)
          })
    })
}
```